# Smallest element in an array

Tags: c

I have written a small program to find the smallest element in an array. I have to use a similar format even though there are much shorter ways to do this. I can't seem to find wha is wrong with the code. The tests are as follows:-

Testing smallest:

array:

Your answer = 2147483647

----pass----

array: 0 -1 5

Your answer = -1

----pass----

array: -1 0 3 -10 3 100

Your answer = 100

----fail----

array: 0 0

Your answer = 0

----pass----

array:

Your answer = 2147483647

----pass----

```
int smallest(int elements[], int size) {
int i;
int temp1 = 0;
int temp2 = elements[0];
if (size <= 0)
{
  return INT_MAX;
}
else
{
for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
  if (elements[i] < temp1)
  {
    elements[i-1] = elements[i];
    temp2 = elements[i];
    elements[i] = temp1;
    temp1 = temp2;
  }
  else
    temp1 = elements[i];
}

return temp1;
}
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indenting

Comment: I don't understand why it is that complicated. You only need to scan the array and compare each element to the currently found minimum.

Comment: Why are you changing the array?  You're doing more work than expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remember current minimum (it can start equal to array's first element), then just loop through the array. If the current element is less than current minimum change the value of current minimum.

```
...    
int min = elements[0];
int i;
for (i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    if (elements[i] < min)
        min = elements[i];
...
```